# update value in collection list item in pymongo

Tags: collections, pymongo

I'm a beginner in pymongo and I have a users collection that stores a user and a comments list 
An instance of a user is like

```
user = {"Name":"Bill" , "Comments":["nice" , "bad"]}
```

What I want is to access the "bad" item and change it to "good"  inside my Comments list but I am beginner and I have trouble with the pymongo syntax . 
This command is used for updating but I do not know how to access the specific list item

```
users.update_one({'key': 'value'}, {'$set': {'key': 'different value'}})
```

I would appreciate your help . Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`positional operator($)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_). This will update only the first element that matches the query condition.

```js
db.collection.update_one(
  { 'name': 'Bill', 'ratings': 'bad' },
  { '$set': 
    { 'ratings.$': 'good' }
  }
)
```

If you want to update all the occurrences of `"bad"` to `"good"`, then you should use [`filtered positional operator($[<identifier>])`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[%3Cidentifier%3E]).

```js
db.collection.update_one(
  { 'name': 'Bill' },
  { '$set': 
    { 'ratings.$[elem]': 'good' }
  },
  array_filters = [{ 'elem': 'bad' }]
)
```